# Adding the double quote in the first field of the file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like this where the field are tab separated:

```
http://article.wn.com/view/wnat51e64f5c0a06e3e18f45e66d5185fc04/                                                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
http://newsok.com/ward-blanks-bruins-in-hurricanes-3-0-win./article/feed/217313?custom_click=rss                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
http://www.neurosoftware.ro/finance/insurance/stock-market/zoom-ctch-wvvi-hiru-couv-stock-alerts-from-stock-pr-com/     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I wanted to add the double quote in the first column of file like this

```
"http://article.wn.com/view/wnat51e64f5c0a06e3e18f45e66d5185fc04/"                                                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
"http://newsok.com/ward-blanks-bruins-in-hurricanes-3-0-win./article/feed/217313?custom_click=rss"                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
"http://www.neurosoftware.ro/finance/insurance/stock-market/zoom-ctch-wvvi-hiru-couv-stock-alerts-from-stock-pr-com/"     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I tried this:

```
awk -F \t '{sub($1, "\"&\""); print}' file
```

I got the result like this:

```
"h"ttp://article.wn.com/view/wnat51e64f5c0a06e3e18f45e66d5185fc04/                                                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
"h"ttp://newsok.com/ward-blanks-bruins-in-hurricanes-3-0-win./article/feed/217313?custom_click=rss                        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0  
"h"ttp://www.neurosoftware.ro/finance/insurance/stock-market/zoom-ctch-wvvi-hiru-couv-stock-alerts-from-stock-pr-com/     0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Are there any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: In `-F \t` the backslash quotes the t in *shell* so awk gets `t` to use as the field separator; to get tab use singequotes `-F'\t'` or doubled backslash `-F\\t`. But you don't appear to need this; valid URLs can't contain whitespace and it appears your other fields don't, so awk's default FS which is effectively [:white:]+ is okay for you. Also, you don't need to `sub()` the whole line you could just do `'{$1="\""$1"\"";print}'` or more readably `-vq='"' '{$1=q$1q;print}'`

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]+)/"\1"/' file
```

It catches the first block of text before a tab (`+` to match at least one character, thanks Jidder in comments!) and prints it back surrounded by double quotes.

Also, your approach would be good if you used `-F"\t"`:

```
awk -F"\t" '{sub($1, "\"&\""); print}' file
```

Whereas this approach might be better (thanks anubhava in comments!)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NF{$1="\"" $1 "\""}1' file
```

This sets input and output field separator to tab. Then, in case there are some fields (`NF` being at least one, that is, no empty lines) it adds the quotes around the first field. Then, `1` performs the default `awk` action: print line.

Comment: Awk won't preserve tab spacing.Also using `sed -r 's/^([^\t]+)/"\1"/'` will prevent it quoting blank lines :)

Comment: Nice, @Jidder, thanks for the input! Updated `sed` command :)

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with awk

```
awk '$1="\""$1"\""' OFS="\t" file
```

If there are blank lines

```
awk 'NF&&$1="\""$1"\""' OFS="\t" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `gensub` funtion from `gawk`:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/^([^[:space:]]+)/, "\"&\"", "")}' infile
```

NOTE: Don´t have to worry about `FS` and `OFS` values.

Comment: $0 at the end not needed as is default.

Comment: Could also use `awk '$0=gensub(/([[:graph:]]+)/,"\"&\"","1")' file`

Comment: ``$0`` is useless , correct! .. i still prefer to use print heere @Jidder

Answer (score 0):

```
echo \t
t
```

The bash literal for a tab character is `$'\t'`.

Comment: awk understands the 2-character string "\t" to mean a tab.

Comment: Ah yes. Your answer is not obvious

Comment: @glennjackman: if this isn't obvious, you shouldn't be programming.

Comment: uh yeah, got me there. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{$1= "\""$1"\""; print}' file
```

Comment: This won't preserve tab spacing

Comment: You should not set `OFS` within code since it not needed and its not changing.  Use `awk -v OFS="\t" 'code' file` or `awk 'code' OFS="\t" file`.  This may be ok too: `awk 'code' OFS=\t file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\S\+/"&"/' file
```

Surround one or more non-spaces by double quotes.